# Failing the build.gradle for serenity plugin

Tags: build.gradle

I am trying to create a serenity project on my machine. For that I have created below build.gradle file in one of the local directory and executed command `gradle build`.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.0.47")     
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'                             

dependencies {
    testCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:core:1.0.47'                          
    testCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.0.47'                
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.11')
    testCompile('org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0')
    testCompile('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7')
}
gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

I am getting below error message on command prompt.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Serenity'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.0.47.
     Required by:
         :Serenity:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/serenity-bdd/serenity-gra
dle-plugin/1.0.47/serenity-gradle-plugin-1.0.47.pom'.
         > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the domain was not available, the error disappear by itself after some time.
In this case, you can also change the mirror repository, for example to
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle
here is a docs link: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N10621